# How to use boolean expression in "declare/set"?

Tags: t-sql

This is not valid...

```
DECLARE @isValid BIT = 0
DECLARE @value INT = 0
SET @isValid = @value <> 0
```

How do I set @isValid when @value is not equal to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL-Server does not know a data-type *boolean*. The type `BIT` is a special integer restricted to `0` or `1`. Expressions can be *evaluated* to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

You might use this:

```
SET @isValid = CASE WHEN @value<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```